# Sci-fi movie shot in desert / pyramid cave

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a movie, possibly in French and possibly directed by a Michel or a Michael. it looked like it was shot on location in late 60s or early 70s in either Tenerife or Lanzarote. Much walking around in the desert...

Had a Jodorowsky feel to it.

Final scene involved a black woman in a cave disappearing into a pyramid void.

unfortunately this is all, movie was showing on a tv in Ibiza some 4 years ago, it was on in the background with the sound down, the moment i noticed how amazing it looked it was too late and the credits began rolling. Have been trying to track it down for 4 years!

I wanna say the black actress was wearing like a blue bikini, she climbed into a cave from the volcanic desert, and once inside a glowing pyramid appeared which she climbed through and fell into a void

Comment: Is this all you remember? No plot, nothing else? Take a look [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info), see if anything else comes to mind.

Comment: unfortunately yes this is all, movie was showing on a tv in Ibiza some 4 years ago, it was on in the background with the sound down, the moment i noticed how amazing it looked it was too late and the credits began rolling. Have been trying to track it down for 4 years!

Comment: You should add that to the question.

Comment: I wanna say the black actress was wearing like a blue bikini, she climbed into a cave from the volcanic desert, and once inside a glowing pyramid appeared which she climbed through and fell into a void....

Comment: ... add that too.

Comment: What was the size of that piramid? Was it just sitting inside the cave, or was it moving? Was it made of bricks?